Django with S3Boto3Storage - After upload, bucket didn't change
I'm using these configuration:
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '*****'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '****'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = 'https://****'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}
AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION  = 'media'
PUBLIC_MEDIA_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = f'{AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL}/{AWS_MEDIA_LOCATION}/

I change the photo on ADMIN, the URL is created, but when I see the bucket, nothing show to me. The URL didn't work for read, of course.
I tried put access configuration on Digital Ocean Space Objects, but.. nothing work.

What version of Django are you using?

Django 5.1.3. When I try upload the image, it goes to file in server (like local), unstyead Space.

Don't use DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE its been deprecated since 4.2 and removed since 5.1, use the STORAGES setting

Thank you @AbdulAzizBarkat! I got.
